# Plotar eixo X gráfico Dendrograma com TF-IDF

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, dados-hierárquicos, clusterização

Estou tentando plotar o Dendrograma com dados que foram vetorizados pelo `TF-idf`, contudo o eixo `x` me apresenta sempre números.

Gostaria de saber como passar para a opção Labels do gráficos, os nomes verdadeiros de cada índice.

```
vect_hierar = TfidfVectorizer(input='filename', stop_words=stopwords_list, encoding='utf8', 

ngram_range=(1,2), min_df=3)

tf_idf_matrix_hierar = vect_hierar.fit_transform(list_of_files).todense()
print(tf_idf_matrix_hierar)

from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.title("Customer Dendograms")
dend = sch.dendrogram(sch.linkage(tf_idf_matrix_hierar, method='ward'))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]